# How does copying an array manually differ from Array.CopyTo()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**Scenario**: I'm about to implement a caching functionality in which I want to cache a serialized object tree that I've received from a web service. The serialized object comes as a byte[] and I basically just want to create a 2nd byte[] that I want to store in case I want to restore the original data without querying the web service again.

**Problem**: If I copy the source byte[] into the target byte[] by using a simple loop, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
   target[i] = source[i];
```

then the BinaryFormatter is not able to deserialize that new byte[]. The exception says:

> Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.

But if I copy the arrays using Buffer.BlockCopy() or Array.CopyTo() the BinaryFormatter has no problems to deserialize the copied byte[].

So my question is, does anyone know why and how copying that array in a loop differs from using those functions? What exactly is missing from that byte[] in the first approach?

Comment: Off by one error in the loop condition.

Comment: The difference between manually copying an array using a loop and copying an array using a predefined method, is that you're more likely to make mistakes doing it yourself, than if you used an equivalent function that's been maintained for many more years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
```

That's copying *all but the last byte*. You want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
```

It would be simpler just to call `Clone()` though:

```
byte[] target = (byte[]) source.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between **Array.CopyTo** and using a loop is, that **Array.CopyTo** calls a native C++ method which is implemented directly in the .NET CLR. It also performs a bit deeper error detection.

If you just need to copy an array to another, use **Array.CopyTo** because it is slightly faster which is remarked when dealing with large arrays.